# Partial conditional constraint in mixed integer linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I have an integer parameter $\rho$, and 2 variables, $g$, which is a matrix of binary variables of shape $(m, t)$, and $x$, which is a list of binary variables of shape $t$.

I want to formulate a constraint that allows me to get the following if condition:

$
if \sum_{m}g_{m,t} \ge \rho \implies x_{t} = 1 \qquad\forall t
$

However, if that condition isn't met, $x_t$ can have a value of 0 or 1.

I suppose that this could be solved with some type of Big-M constraint, but I can't figure out how to formulate it.

Thanks you very much in advance!

**EDIT:**

To clarify:

$
if \sum_{m}g_{m,t} < \rho \implies x_{t} \le 1 \qquad\forall t
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalently, you want to enforce the contrapositive
$$x_t = 0 \implies \sum_m g_{m,t} \le \rho - 1$$
You can do so via linear big-M constraint
$$\sum_m g_{m,t} - \rho + 1 \le M_t x_t $$

Comment: Hi @RobPratt . Thanks for your answer. However, I think that is not valid for me. As I said in the question if $\sum_{m}g_{m,t}<\rho$ then $x_t$ is free to get 0 or 1 as value, and its value will only depend on other constraints in the problem. Just if $\sum_{m}g_{m,t}\ge\rho \implies x_{t} = 1$. If I use your approach I will enforce 0 when maybe it should be 1 depending on that other constraints.

Comment: My formulation does in fact do what you want.  Just check the two cases.  If $x_t=0$ then $\sum_m g_{m,t} -\rho+1\le 0$. If $x_t=1$ then $\sum_m g_{m,t} -\rho+1\le M_t$, which is redundant by the choice of $M_t$.

Comment: Reading more carefully, you are right Rob. I've just implemented it in my code and works fine. Thanks you very much!